# Error : ResourcesNotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1

Tags: android

While trying to parse the following strings to date time using simpledatetime format, there is an error showing like this:

```
02-16 13:07:40.455: E/AndroidRuntime(676): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-16 13:07:40.455: E/AndroidRuntime(676): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.timer/com.example.timer.MainActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
```

The code which I have written is given below. Please tell me what is the possible reason for this error.

```
    String date1="17-Feb-14 12:54:34 AM";

    String date2="15-Feb-14 9:55:23 PM";


    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy hh:mm:ss aa");
    try {
        Date dt1=sdf.parse(date1);
        Date dt2=sdf.parse(date2);
    int value=dt1.compareTo(dt2);

    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I get this date and time format from my server as a string. So I need to convert it into Date and time for processing at the client side. Please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, String.valueOf(value), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

You are trying to use integer as a message in `Toast`

P.S. You can use `int` as a message, but only when you are reffering a resource declared in your `R` class, please take a look here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toast.html#makeText%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20int%29

Answer (score 1):

You have used an `int` for `value` but `Toast.makeText()` requires a string or the id of a string resource (e.g. `R.string.helloWorld`).

Change

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

To

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, value.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

Reason for this, second parameter is of int/String type. If you pass the int then which points to any resouces, Android check this `id` exist in the resources `R` if not then it throw the `ResourcesNotFound`.

Android generate the `id` of each resources in the `R.java`.

So in your case you have passed the integer value and android trying to look that `id` in the `R.java` that is not available.

So you have to convert the integer to string using the `.toString()` method.

This is method overloading here where you can pass the Resources Id or any string in  the second parameter.